# how to properly compile files in node js project

Tags: typescript, sass, handlebars.js, node-sass

created a small projec. I am
using sass,  node js,  typescript, handlebars in it.

my script to compiling project

> ```
> "start": "nodemon index.ts",
> "build": "tsc --noEmit false && sass -w src/:dist/css/"
> ```

it works almost

All files are compiled as I need,
I miss moving the handlebars file to the main compilation folder (dist)

how to organize it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwGS8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for sass i personally use this simple build process
[image: build process]

> package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "watch:sass": "sass --watch sass/main.sass  dist/css/style.css",
    "compile:sass": "sass --no-source-map sass/main.sass  dist/css/style.comp.css",
    "concat:css": "concat -o dist/css/style.concat.css dist/css/icon-fonts.css dist/css/style.comp.css",
    "prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer  -b 'last 10 versions' dist/css/style.concat.css  -o dist/css/style.prefix.css",
    "compress:css": "sass --style compressed dist/css/style.prefix.css dist/css/style.css ",
    "build:css": "npm-run-all compile:sass concat:css prefix:css compress:css "
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "concat": "^1.0.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss-cli": "^9.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.49.4"
  },
```